# Correct way to update record through javascript in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I want to update a record in a database through javascript async in mvc4 \ EF5.
So, I have js object with `Id, StartDate, EndDate`. Should I render hidden edit form, paste values, and submit form? Is there an easier way? Can I add a smart action to controller that will allow me to edit record. (AFAIK, it is not safe to edit record through GET).
* I'm using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/) and want to send an update to database on schedule event resize.

Comment: jQuery has a `.post()` method built in: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your object using the following code:

```
function onUpdate(event) {
    $.post(
        '@Url.Action("Update")', 
        { id: event.id, startdate: event.start, enddate: event.end }
    ).done(function() {
        alert('Update success');
    });
}
```

You should also avoid manipulating data by GET request. Consider situation that somebody will send you email with minified link (so you don't know what it is) that edit your record and you click it. To prevent this add to your action HttpPost attribute and consider using [AntiForgeryToken](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do this, it posts null values into my controller. (Dates are shown as 01/01/0001)